# Bootstrap SASS Change spacer value depending on breakpoint

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, sass

I have created a new spacer size within bootstrap which is being used throughout my project. As the value is quite large, I would like to be able to set it so that on smaller devices that value is smaller and brings all spaces down.

I know that I can use different breakpoint classes to change to smaller spacers on smaller devices, but I have so many places to change I am hoping I can do it within SASS/CSS.

My spacer looks like this:

```
$spacers: (
    6: ($spacer * 4)
);
```

Is it possible to use an if statement or media query to change the value depending on screen size?

Answer (score 0):

One option is to adapt the spacing utilities Bootstrap provides. Here's `utilities/_spacing.scss` from Bootstrap 4 for example:

```
// Margin and Padding

@each $breakpoint in map-keys($grid-breakpoints) {
  @include media-breakpoint-up($breakpoint) {
    $infix: breakpoint-infix($breakpoint, $grid-breakpoints);

    @each $prop, $abbrev in (margin: m, padding: p) {
      @each $size, $length in $spacers {
        .#{$abbrev}#{$infix}-#{$size} { #{$prop}: $length !important; }
        .#{$abbrev}t#{$infix}-#{$size},
        .#{$abbrev}y#{$infix}-#{$size} {
          #{$prop}-top: $length !important;
        }
        .#{$abbrev}r#{$infix}-#{$size},
        .#{$abbrev}x#{$infix}-#{$size} {
          #{$prop}-right: $length !important;
        }
        .#{$abbrev}b#{$infix}-#{$size},
        .#{$abbrev}y#{$infix}-#{$size} {
          #{$prop}-bottom: $length !important;
        }
        .#{$abbrev}l#{$infix}-#{$size},
        .#{$abbrev}x#{$infix}-#{$size} {
          #{$prop}-left: $length !important;
        }
      }
    }

    // Negative margins (e.g., where `.mb-n1` is negative version of `.mb-1`)
    @each $size, $length in $spacers {
      @if $size != 0 {
        .m#{$infix}-n#{$size} { margin: -$length !important; }
        .mt#{$infix}-n#{$size},
        .my#{$infix}-n#{$size} {
          margin-top: -$length !important;
        }
        .mr#{$infix}-n#{$size},
        .mx#{$infix}-n#{$size} {
          margin-right: -$length !important;
        }
        .mb#{$infix}-n#{$size},
        .my#{$infix}-n#{$size} {
          margin-bottom: -$length !important;
        }
        .ml#{$infix}-n#{$size},
        .mx#{$infix}-n#{$size} {
          margin-left: -$length !important;
        }
      }
    }

    // Some special margin utils
    .m#{$infix}-auto { margin: auto !important; }
    .mt#{$infix}-auto,
    .my#{$infix}-auto {
      margin-top: auto !important;
    }
    .mr#{$infix}-auto,
    .mx#{$infix}-auto {
      margin-right: auto !important;
    }
    .mb#{$infix}-auto,
    .my#{$infix}-auto {
      margin-bottom: auto !important;
    }
    .ml#{$infix}-auto,
    .mx#{$infix}-auto {
      margin-left: auto !important;
    }
  }
}
```

You can remove the breakpoint declarations, strip out the `#{$infix}` variable, define your own custom set of spacers, and then manually wrap it in a breakpoint declaration to set your overrides.

So for example, if we want to change all the spacers from the defaults for small screens it could look like this.

```
// Spacing for mobile
@include media-breakpoint-down('sm') {
  $spacers: (
  0: 0,
  1: $spacer / 2,
  2: $spacer * 0.75,
  3: $spacer * 1.5,
  4: $spacer * 2,
  5: $spacer * 3,
  );
  
  @each $prop, $abbrev in (margin: m, padding: p) {
    @each $size, $length in $spacers {
      .#{$abbrev}-#{$size} { #{$prop}: $length !important; }
      .#{$abbrev}t-#{$size},
      .#{$abbrev}y-#{$size} {
        #{$prop}-top: $length !important;
      }
      .#{$abbrev}r-#{$size},
      .#{$abbrev}x-#{$size} {
        #{$prop}-right: $length !important;
      }
      .#{$abbrev}b-#{$size},
      .#{$abbrev}y-#{$size} {
        #{$prop}-bottom: $length !important;
      }
      .#{$abbrev}l-#{$size},
      .#{$abbrev}x-#{$size} {
        #{$prop}-left: $length !important;
      }
    }
  }
  
  // Negative margins (e.g., where `.mb-n1` is negative version of `.mb-1`)
  @each $size, $length in $spacers {
    @if $size != 0 {
      .m-n#{$size} { margin: -$length !important; }
      .mt-n#{$size},
      .my-n#{$size} {
        margin-top: -$length !important;
      }
      .mr-n#{$size},
      .mx-n#{$size} {
        margin-right: -$length !important;
      }
      .mb-n#{$size},
      .my-n#{$size} {
        margin-bottom: -$length !important;
      }
      .ml-n#{$size},
      .mx-n#{$size} {
        margin-left: -$length !important;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

It feels a little hacky but should get the job done for this scenario. Otherwise you're better off changing your base font size at different viewports so all rem units adjust accordingly or using the breakpoint utility classes as intended.